# How to solve a system of equations with symbolic dimension in Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I have a vector of unknowns x_i, with i=1,...,N, where N  is symbolic, and I have some nonlinear system of M equations, f_m(x_1,...,x_N) = 0, for m=1,...,M. How should I approach this problem with Sympy?

To make things more concrete: For example, suppose that I have the following system, described by the generic equation `eq` below, valid for all `i`:

```
N = Symbol('N', integer = True)
i = Idx('i', (1,N))
x = IndexedBase('x', real = True)
eq = exp(x[i]) + Sum(x[i], i) # This is a generic equation, valid for all i
```

How should I approach this? Is there a way to look for a solution for all x[i]?
How to state this problem to Sympy? If there are clarifications needed, I would be glad to provide them.